# Como eu faço para inserir dados em uma tabela com chave estrangeira no django?

Tags: django

class Endereco(models.Model):

```
cep = models.IntegerField('cep', max_length=10)
rua = models.CharField('rua', max_length=100)
numero = models.CharField('numero', max_length=10)
bairro = models.CharField('bairro', max_length=50)
estado = models.CharField('estado', max_length=50)
cidade = models.CharField('cidade', max_length=50)
usuario = models.ForeignKey('Usuario',on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='usuario')
```

Answer (score -2):

Supondo que exista um usuário de username `johndoe`:

```
user = User.objects.get(username='johndoe')
```

Nesse caso, você criaria um objeto de `Endereco` da seguinte maneira:

```
Endereco.objects.create(
    cep='70000000',
    rua='Rua X',
    numero='10',
    bairro='Bairro Y',
    estado='Estado Z',
    cidade='Cidade W',
    usuario=user
)
```